# In a new nixos derivation, based on a binary distribution, why am I getting an error referring to nativeBuildInputs?

Tags: nixos

I'm trying to make a nixos package from a program distributed in binary form only. Like most, links to the standard linker and to libraries don't match a nixos system, so I'm trying to create a new derivation that uses `patchelf` to update those link. I'm basing my work off of the `zoom-us` package already in the packages repository.

However, when I try to install the package, I get this error:

```
savanni@lapis:~  $ nix-env -i all --show-trace
replacing old ‘all’
installing ‘all’
error: while evaluating the attribute ‘pkgs’ of the derivation ‘all’ at /nix/store/1fxfp03ya08rnzrzyxy7dhca3c5qm0jk-nixos-16.09.1829.c88e67d/nixos/pkgs/build-support/trivial-builders.nix:10:14:
while evaluating the attribute ‘nativeBuildInputs’ of the derivation ‘GoPanda’ at /home/savanni/.nixpkgs/gopanda2.nix:9:5:
cannot coerce a set to a string, at /home/savanni/.nixpkgs/gopanda2.nix:9:5
```

Here is the text of my derivation:

```
{ cairo, fetchurl, glib, patchelf, stdenv, xorg }:
stdenv.mkDerivation rec {
    name = "GoPanda";
    version = "2";
    meta = {
        homepage = "http://pandanet-igs.com/communities/gopanda2";
    };

    src = fetchurl {
        url = "http://pandanet-igs.com/gopanda2/installer/stable/linux-64/gopanda2-linux-64.tar.gz";
        sha256 = "6d0a13e81a4646779331ff182acdbf9fe7982b2659f12a794a50897ea7368e1c";
    };  

    phases = [ "unpackPhase" "installPhase" ];
    nativeBuildInputs = [ ];
    buildInputs = [
        cairo
        glib
        xorg
    ];

    libPath = stdenv.lib.makeLibraryPath buildInputs;

    installPhase = ''
        mkdir -p $out/bin
        cp GoPanda2 $out/bin/GoPanda2
        patchelf \
            --set-interpreter $(cat $NIX_CC/nix-support/dynamic-linker) \
            --set-rpath ${libPath} \
            $out/bin/GoPanda2
    '';
}
```

If I remove the `nativeBuildInputs` line, the `buildInputs` line, the `libPath` line, and references to `libPath`, I get a successful build, but an executable that doesn't know where to find the libraries. So I know I need to specify the libraries. Furthermore, I can start with the above code and add things to `nativeBuildInputs`, and still get the same error.

But the question is, why is there a failing coercion around `nativeBuildInputs`, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue lay in the `xorg` entry in `buildInputs`.

`xorg` is a collection, not an individual module. So far as I can see, the expectation for `buildInputs` is that everything in the list be coercible to a string, and apparently modules can be coerced in such a way (presumably to the module name). A list cannot be coerced in such a way.

The reference to `nativeBuildInputs` presumably indicates that `buildInputs` gets mushed into `nativeBuildInputs`.

Here is the text of a derivation that builds but is simply missing some of the libraries that I have not yet included from `xorg`. I'll replace it with a complete derivation once I have the application completely working.

```
{ pkgs ? import <nixpkgs> {}
, cairo ? pkgs.cairo
, fetchurl ? pkgs.fetchurl
, glib ? pkgs.glib
, patchelf ? pkgs.patchelf
, stdenv ? pkgs.stdenv
, xorg ? pkgs.xorg
}:
stdenv.mkDerivation rec {
    name = "GoPanda";
    version = "2";
    meta = {
        homepage = "http://pandanet-igs.com/communities/gopanda2";
    };

    src = fetchurl {
        url = "http://pandanet-igs.com/gopanda2/installer/stable/linux-64/gopanda2-linux-64.tar.gz";
        sha256 = "6d0a13e81a4646779331ff182acdbf9fe7982b2659f12a794a50897ea7368e1c";
    };

    phases = [ "unpackPhase" "installPhase" ];
    buildInputs = [
        cairo
        glib
        xorg.libX11
    ];

    libPath = stdenv.lib.makeLibraryPath buildInputs;

    installPhase = ''
        mkdir -p $out/share
        mkdir -p $out/bin
        cp -r locales $out/share
        cp GoPanda2 $out/bin/GoPanda2
        patchelf \
            --set-interpreter $(cat $NIX_CC/nix-support/dynamic-linker) \
            --set-rpath ${libPath} \
            $out/bin/GoPanda2
    '';
}
```